# How to Display Python output in VS code terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, vscode-code-runner

So.. whenever i try running Python codes in Vs code the output isn't shown in terminal part but the output part, can someone tell me how to make the output visible in terminal part plss

Comment: use `print()` statements

Answer (score 0):

Running code in VS Code defaults to outputting results in the **TERMINAL** panel.

[image]

Have you downloaded and installed the **[Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)** extension? and run the code with the option ***Run Code*** it brings?

If so, please add the following configuration to your **settings.json** file, this will make **Code Runner** run the code and output the result in the **TERMINAL** panel.

```json
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I learned in another answer here the possibility of using the "Interactive Window" to see output content.

[Use "Run in interactive window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frWEM.png)

I'm not sure this is standard or not. I have Jupyter installed and also a couple extensions. But here's a guide to use it:

[https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GALJ.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34746681)